# Matalb code Error in Selecting Disc view of Waves

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matlab-figure

I am getting an error when I run this code for disc waves. The code is attached.
The Error is in line 137 and 292. Please help in resolving issue.

```
function waves
% WAVES  Wave equation in one and two space dimensions.
%   The two-dimensional domains include a pi-by-pi square, a unit disc,
%   a three-quarter circular sector and the L-shaped union of three squares.
%   The eigenfunctions of the square are sin(m*x)*sin(n*y).  With polar
%   coordinates, the eigenfunctions of the disc and the sector involve Bessel
%   functions.  The eigenfunctions of the L-shaped domain also involve
 
%   Bessel functions and are computed by the MATLAB function membranetx.m.
% 2-D eigenvalues and eigenfunctions
m = 11;   % Determines number of grid points
speed = 1;
bvals = [1; 0; 0; 0; 0];
t = 0;
while bvals(5) == 0
   % Initialize figure
   shg
   clf reset
   set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on','menubar','none','tag','', ...
       'numbertitle','off','name','Waves','colormap',hot(64));
   for k= 1:5
      b(k) = uicontrol('style','toggle','value',bvals(k), ...
          'units','normal','position',[.15*k .01 .14 .05]);
   end
   set(b(1),'style','pop','string', ...
      {'1-d','square','disc','sector'})
   set(b(2),'string','modes/wave')
   set(b(3),'string','slower')
   set(b(4),'string','faster')
   set(b(5),'string','close')
   if bvals(3)==1
 
      speed = speed/sqrt(2);
      set(b(3),'value',0);
   end
   if bvals(4)==1
      speed = speed*sqrt(2);

      set(b(4),'value',0);
   end
   bvals = cell2mat(get(b,'value'));
   region = bvals(1);
   modes = bvals(2)==0;
   if region == 1
 
      % 1-D
      x = (0:4*m)/(4*m)*pi;
 
      orange = [1 1/3 0];
      gray = get(gcf,'color');
      if modes
         % 1-D modes
  
         for k = 1:4
            subplot(2,2,k)
            h(k) = plot(x,zeros(size(x)));
            axis([0 pi -3/2 3/2])
            set(h(k),'color',orange,'linewidth',3)
            set(gca,'color',gray','xtick',[],'ytick',[])
         end
         delta = 0.005*speed;
         bvs = bvals;
         while all(bvs == bvals)
            t = t + delta;
            for k = 1:4
               u = sin(k*t)*sin(k*x);
               set(h(k),'ydata',u)
            end
            drawnow
 
            bvs = cell2mat(get(b,'value'));
         end
      else
         % 1-D wave
         h = plot(x,zeros(size(x)));
         axis([0 pi -9/4 9/4])
         set(h,'color',orange,'linewidth',3)
         set(gca,'color',gray','xtick',[],'ytick',[])
         delta = 0.005*speed;
         a = 1./(1:4);
         bvs = bvals;
         while all(bvs == bvals)
            t = t + delta;
            u = zeros(size(x));
            for k = 1:4
               u = u + a(k)*sin(k*t)*sin(k*x);
            end

            set(h,'ydata',u)
            drawnow
            bvs = cell2mat(get(b,'value'));
         end
      end

 
   elseif region <= 5
      switch region
         case 2
            % Square
            x = (0:2*m)/(2*m)*pi;
            y = x';
            lambda = zeros(4,1);
            V = cell(4,1);
            k = 0;
            for i = 1:2
               for j = 1:2
                  k = k+1;
                  lambda(k) = i^2 + j^2;
                  V{k} = sin(i*y)*sin(j*x);
               end
            end
            ax = [0 pi 0 pi -1.75 1.75];
         case 3
            % Disc, mu = zeros of J_0(r) and J_1(r)
            mu = [bjzeros(0,2) bjzeros(1,2)];
            [r,theta] = meshgrid((0:m)/m,(-m:m)/m*pi);
            x = r.*cos(theta);
            y = r.*sin(theta);
            V = cell(4,1);
            k = 0;
            for j = 0:1
               for i = 1:2
                  k = k+1;
                  if j == 0
                     V{k} = besselj(0,mu(k)*r);
                  else
 
                     V{k} = besselj(j,mu(k)*r).*sin(j*theta);
                  end
                  V{k} = V{k}/max(max(abs(V{k})));
               end
            end
            lambda = mu.^2;
            ax = [-1 1 -1 1 -1.75 1.75];
         case 4
            % Circular sector , mu = zeros of J_(2/3)(r) and J_(4/3)(r)
            mu = [bjzeros(2/3,2) bjzeros(4/3,2)];
            [r,theta] = meshgrid((0:m)/m,(3/4)*(0:2*m)/m*pi);
            x = r.*cos(theta+pi);
            y = r.*sin(theta+pi);
            V = cell(4,1);
            k = 0;
            for j = 1:2
               for i = 1:2
                  k = k+1;
                  alpha = 2*j/3;
                  V{k} = besselj(alpha,mu(k)*r).*sin(alpha*theta);
                  V{k} = V{k}/max(max(abs(V{k})));
               end
            end
            lambda = mu.^2;
            ax = [-1 1 -1 1 -1.75 1.75];

 
         case 5\
            % L-membrane
            x = (-m:m)/m;
            y = x';
            lambda = zeros(4,1);
            V = cell(4,1);
            for k = 1:4
               [L lambda(k)] = membranetx(k,m,9,9);
               L(m+2:2*m+1,m+2:2*m+1) = NaN;
               V{k} = rot90(L,-1);
            end
            ax = [-1 1 -1 1 -1.75 1.75];
      end
      if modes
         % 2-D modes
         p = [.02 .52 .02 .52];
         q = [.52 .52 .02 .02];
         for k = 1:4
            axes('position',[p(k) q(k) .46 .46]);
            h(k) = surf(x,y,zeros(size(V{k})));
            axis(ax)
            axis off
            view(225,30);
            caxis([-1.5 1]);
         end
         delta = .08*speed;
         mu = sqrt(lambda(:));
         bvs = bvals;
         while all(bvs == bvals)
            t = t + delta;
            for k = 1:4
               U = 1.5*sin(mu(k)*t)*V{k};
               set(h(k),'zdata',U)
               set(h(k),'cdata',U)
            end
            drawnow
            bvs = cell2mat(get(b,'value'));
         end

 
      else
         % 2-D wave
  
         h = surf(x,y,zeros(size(V{1})));
         axis(ax);
         axis off
         view(225,30);
         caxis([-1.5 1]);
         delta = .02*speed;
         mu = sqrt(lambda(:));
         a = 1.25./(1:4);
         bvs = bvals;
         while all(bvs == bvals)
            t = t + delta;
            U = zeros(size(V{1}));
            for k = 1:4
               U = U + a(k)*sin(mu(k)*t)*V{k};
            end
            set(h,'zdata',U)
            set(h,'cdata',U)
            drawnow
            bvs = cell2mat(get(b,'value'));
         end
      end
   elseif region == 6
      figure
      bizcard
      set(b(1),'value',1)
   end
   % Retain uicontrol values
   bvals = cell2mat(get(b,'value'));
end
close
% -------------------------------

function z = bjzeros(n,k)
% BJZEROS  Zeros of the Bessel function.
% z = bjzeros(n,k) is the first k zeros of besselj(n,x)
% delta must be chosen so that the linear search can take
% steps as large as possible without skipping any zeros.
% delta is approx bjzero(0,2)-bjzero(0,1)
delta = .99*pi;

 
Jsubn = inline('besselj(n,x)''x','n');
a = n+1;
fa = besselj(n,a);
z = zeros(1,k);
j = 0;
while j < k
   b = a + delta;
   fb = besselj(n,b);
   if sign(fb) ~= sign(fa)
      j = j+1;
      z(j) = fzerotx(Jsubn,[a b],n);
   end
   a = b;
   fa = fb;
end
```

Comment: I copied your code and got an easily fixable error, the line with case 5\ needs to have the \ deleted.  The code then ran, but I did get an error that fzerotx function does not exist, so you left that out.  You said there was an error on line 292, but I only have 253 lines of code when I copy your code, so perhaps the formatting gets changed due to copying and pasting.  It would be helpful if you listed the exact steps to get an error and what the error messages are.

Comment: Agreed, `fzerotx()` is not a built-in function it needs to be defined by you either locally or in another `.m` function script.